# Visibility widget ON/OFF refreshing entire page

Tags: flutter, widget

How to stop refreshing of Widgets if Visibility Widget not allowing child widget to show?

Below example showing the `Visibility` Widget which ON/OFF child widget based on the condition, but with this Widget hiding and showing, the other widget has to adjust/re-rendered.

So, All wanted to stop the re-rendering of other widgets? how can I do that?

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    MyWidget1(),
    MyWidget2(),
    Visibility(
          visible: condition == true,
          child: MyWidget3(),
   ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't want other widgets to adjust their position and stay at the same position irrespective of whether `MyWidget3` is visible or invisible?

Comment: yes, that is what I want, I found the solution will be posting here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the solution!!!**

`Visibility` Widget few properties which can help us to resolve this issue,

**maintainState:** maintain the States in the child widget when it’s hidden.

**maintainAnimation:** maintain the animations within the child widget when it’s hidden.

**maintainSize:** maintain the child widget space when it’s hidden.

With all this properties we can keep the `MyWidget3(`) widget as it is,

```
 Visibility(
   visible: condition == true,
   maintainState: true,
   maintainAnimation: true,
   maintainSize: true,
   child: MyWidget3(),
 )
```

Comment: How will the condition be changed - through `setState` ?

Answer (score -1):

Most common and easy solution is to use

provider - https://pub.dev/packages/provider

package to manage your widgets state, and then you can use consumer widget to rebuild your widgets that need to be updated.

Comment: Can you give the explanation with a code snippet ?